# How to calculate real bitrate of incoming rtsp stream with GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, bitrate

Is there any way to calculate real bitrate of incoming RTSP stream?

I've used "current-level-bytes" property of queue element, but result was unacceptable. I've also tried gst_element_query_duration with GST_FORMAT_BYTES on rtspsrc but it gives 0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may use `gst-play-1.0 -v your_rtsp_stream_uri` and you'll see in the stats the bitrate that will take some time to converge to its true value. You may filter with grep such as `gst-play-1.0 -v your_rtsp_stream_uri | grep GstSelectorPad`, let it run for one minute and you would have a good estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [gst-perf](https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-perf) in your pipeline, it will display the framerate and the bitrate.

If you want to know how to calculate the bitrate, take a look at the code. The plugin is a transform type, and in the transform handler `gst_perf_transform_ip`, the bitrate is calculated using the time between buffers and the buffer size (`gst_util_get_timestamp`, `gst_buffer_get_size`).

If you have a pipeline in C, you can add this functionality to a `appsrc`/`appsink` part, or use a `pad` to catch all buffers, and do these operations.

Comment: gst-perf fits perfectly, thanks.